# Pressing back button exits the app instead of navigating backwards in the WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am working on a WebView android app. I am unable to fix an issue in my app to back navigate. I am using this code and tried all modifications can be made to this.

```
public class DeviceActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView web;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(false);
        web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        // Our application's main page will be loaded
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fbp/index.html");

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (web.canGoBack()) {
                    web.goBack();
                } else {
                    // My exit alert code goes here.
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't navigate back but instead, it exits the app.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this in your `Activity` code (not in `onCreate()` or nested anywhere else)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (web.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
        web.goBack();
    }
    else {
        // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
        super.onBackPressed(); // finishes activity
    }
}
```

This will navigate back through the `WebView` history stack until it is empty and then perform the default action (in this case it finishes the activity).

You should probably also set your WebViewClient to have `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` return `true` or you won't load any links.

Comment: I am getting problems while inserting exit dialogue code, can help me in making an exit dialogue here?

Comment: Sure - open a new question with your specifc problem, what you have tried, where it's going wrong, and I'll help if I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have kept the following block in onCreate() method.

```
if (web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();       
}
else {
    //My exit alert code goes here.    

}
```

Instead keep the same code in onBackPressed() like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

also refer to [Getting Started: WebView-based Applications for Web Developers in Android](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted)

Answer (score 1):

We can use webview method to navigate forward and backward. method boolean `canGoForward()` for Gets whether this WebView has a forward history item. `canGoBack()` for Gets whether this WebView has a back history item. `goBack()` Goes back in the history of this WebView and `goForward()` Goes forward in the history of this WebView. this is my implementation :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.forward_btn:
                if (mWebView.canGoForward()){
                    mWebView.goForward();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak ada halaman lagi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.backward_btn:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak bisa kembali!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.reload_btn:
                layoutLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mWebView.reload();
                break;
            case R.id.back_btn:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
    }
```