# Back icon to return to current webview page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Am working on Android studio,Initially I opened my url within webview,I want to provide a back button and when button is onclicked it has return to current webview page i.e source of url in webview.

Comment: @ski check this post [Java bridge Android](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` have a method called [`goBack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goBack()), but this should be called if your `WebView` allows you to go back via [`canGoBack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack()).
You should override both `onBackPressed()` and `onKeyDown()` and there use this method.
Something like this

```
Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { 

        //if Back key pressed and this WebView has a back history item.
        webView.goBack(); 
        return true; 
     } 
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: How to provide a custom button icon along with external URL in web-view, If I on-click the icon it should redirect to  web view page where it got navigated.

Comment: You can use a `RelativeLayout` with a `WebView` and a `Button` in your xml. `RelativeLayouts` allow you to place views on top of each other and also provide a powerful way to arrange views inside (relative to other views or parent edges). After you do that, you can set click listeners on button and control the webview like that

Answer (score 0):

from that , [Back Navigation in a Webview Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941930/back-navigation-in-a-webview-android-app)

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if (web.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
        web.goBack();
    }
    else {
        // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
        super.onBackPressed(); // finishes activity
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

on Click of back Button You add this

```
     if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            }
```